# How to sync mysql remote database daily ?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a database that contains orders , products ..etc. I have another system that generates reports based on this database. Due to heavy load i want to separate those systems Where i have the master database for products .. and a slave database for the reporting system.

Whats the best approach to build this given that :

1. I dont care about real time data . Syncing will be done once a day.
2. I might have a different schema for the slave database.

Comment: for same database you will have different schema on slave ?

Comment: I only need numbers in the slave database . I can sync the whole database but it'll be an overhead.

Comment: what do you mean by numbers?

Comment: The simplest way to sync your database is to set master slave replication but in that your slave tables structure should be exact copy of master.

Comment: Please have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html this is what replication does.

Comment: @IyadAlaqel which option did you end up using? Does the reporting database needs to have additional tables, indexes, views, storedprocedures or functions?